# Windows Server 2016 Active Directory : A computer with a specific user can see all the network

Tags: networking, active-directory, windows-server-2016

On my local network managed by Windows Server 2016 and users with a domain, a computer (ORD-A) with a specific user (USR-A) can see the whole network even though I have already organized access to every folder on the network.

What is still weird is that on this computer (ORD-A), if I use another user (USER-X), I have no problem.

And if I use this user (USR-A) on another computer (ORD-X), I also have no problem.

Has someone had this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a rights problem : Did you configure groups to access those data ? Maybe the user has asministrator rights or is part of a group that can access all the network ?

Or if it's a network problem : Did you check the IP of the user on the computer ? Maybe the RJ45 port used by the computer is on a specific VLAN ?

Or maybe the user used to have specific rights and the computer need a GPO update to delete those specific access ?

Comment: yes, I believe this is all ok, because the user if logged from another computer, I don't have this problem.

and what I've seen now is a known issue:

if this user from this computer use: "//server/*" he has all the access
but if he use: "//192.168.x.x/*" he has defined access only.

Comment: Well if you can't find the problem, purge the computer and re install an OS on top. Then do the test again with the user ^^